# Homogenous polynomials as sum or differences of squares and symmetric polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I seem to recall that a general *homogenous* real polynomial $P$ of even degree in $n$ variables, $n\geq 3,$
cannot always be expressed as $P(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)=\sum_j a_j Q_j^2(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{R},$ and the $Q_j^2$ are *homogenous of the same degree* as $P.$
(Please, correct me if I am wrong).

Now, what if we know that $P$ is symmetric? 
Is it still true that a general polynomial cannot be expressed as above?
And if it can, what if we require that the $Q_j$ themselves are symmetric?

**Question:** If $P$ is symmetric and homogenous of even degree,
can it be expressed as a sum/difference of squares of homogenous and symmetric polynomials?

I know that if $P$ is symmetric, and $P(x_1+t,x_2+t,\dotsc,x_n+t)=P(x_1,\dotsc,x_n),$
then there is always such a representation as the one above, but can one lose the translation-invariant condition and still have sum-and-difference of squares representation?

Comment: Every element of a ring in which $2$ is a unit is the difference of two squares: $P=(P+1/4)^2-(P-1/4)^2$.

Comment: Ah, let me rephrase that question a bit, I realized that I have some conditions on Q

Comment: @Per: you mean the degree of Q is 1/2 that of P...So you are looking at a higher degree version of Gauss's decomposition of quadratic forms?

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam: Yes, I believe so. (Thank you very much for the input on one of my previous questions by the way.)

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, if $P$ is of odd degree, you won't find any $Q$ such that $Q^2$ has the same degree as $P$. 

Comment: At the risk of stating the even more obvious, the degree of $Q^{2}$ is twice the degree of $Q$...

Comment: Yes, P is of even degree, of course.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious I think Per is well able to correct these trivialities about degrees.

Comment: This is not important for the question, but still, I'd like to correct the first paragraph of the question. Every real homogeneous form of degree $2d$ can be written as a real linear combination of squares of real homogeneous forms of degree $d$. It's enough to check, say, monomials can be written as real linear combinations of $\ell^{2d}$'s, which in turn are squares, $(\ell^d)^2$. Perhaps you are thinking of the problem that a non-negative form of degree $2d$ can't necessarily be written as a positive combination of squares.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Correct, I must have been thinking about non-negative polynomials as sums-of-squares...
But the question is still open - if the original polynomial is symmetric, can we ask that the squares themselves are symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My college provided me with a simple example:
$$x^2 + xy + y^2$$ cannot be expressed as a sum/difference of symmetric, homogenous polynomials of degree 1, for obvious reasons.

(Each homogenous, symmetric polynomial of degree 1 in two variables are of the form a(x+y).
Thus, all possible $Q_j$ are of the form $a'(x+y)^2$ which, of course, cannot give the polynomial above.)